# Removing "Use Gift Certificate" in Opencart 3.0.2.0

Tags: opencart, shopping-cart, opencart-module, opencart-3

How to remove the "Use Gift Certificate" option from the Shopping cart in Opencart 3.0.2.0?

I try to disable the "Gift Voucher" in the admin panel *Extensions > Order Totals* but for some reason it doesn't accept it and it is still enabled. 
Moreover, while I try all this, the title of my Shopping cart was somehow changed from:
"**Shopping Cart**" to "**Use Gift Certificate**"

How to restore the title and to remove "Use Gift Certificate" option?

Here, I apply an image of my current shopping cart outlook:
[Shopping Cart print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcnxL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To restore your the title from: "Use Gift Certificate" to "Shopping Cart" go to:
catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/cart.php at line 3:

```
$_['heading_title']            = 'Shopping Cart';
```

for more information your can visit [this](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=62087)

Answer (score 0):

This is a 3.0 bug that you can fix by doing this:

IN:

```
/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php
```

AFTER:

```
if ($this->cart->hasProducts() || !empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
```

ADD:

```
$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
```

Comment: Hi @noufalcep...can uh help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125643/fetch-values-in-tr-from-values-coming-from-for-each-loop-in-tds